# how to open desktop view in firefox mobile browser

Tags: javascript, html

How to open desktop view in mozila mobile browser using view port. I tried every thing to open desktop view in mozila mobile browse. I'm using this

```
// Store the meta element
var viewport_meta = document.getElementById('viewport-meta');

// Define our viewport meta values
    var viewports = {
    default: viewport_meta.getAttribute('content'),
    landscape: 'width=990'
};

// Change the viewport value based on screen.width
var viewport_set = function() {
    if ( screen.width > 768 )
        viewport_meta.setAttribute( 'content',viewports.landscape );
    else
        viewport_meta.setAttribute( 'content', viewports.default );
}

// Set the correct viewport value on page load
    viewport_set();

// Set the correct viewport after device orientation change or resize
window.onresize = function() { 
    viewport_set(); 
}
```

Comment: Please, show us the code you used while trying.